# ScrollBar horizontal indicator ListView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

With a horizontal ListView, the scroll bar only shows while you are scrolling. To solve this, I wrapped my ListView inside a ScrollView and set

```
showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}
```

but still the horizontal scroll bar only shows WHILE scrolling, how can I permanently show it?